# Connect to MongoDB server through Elastic IP

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, networking, ip

I have one AWS EC2 instance. I have installed MongoDB there.

```
Private IP :- 10.x.x.x
Port :- 27017
```

I can ssh into that system and connect the MongoDB server by using private IP within the VPN.

`10.x.x.x:27017` - MongoDB is running here.

But, I have assigned one Elastic IP into that EC2 instance.

```
Public IP :- 132.x.x.x
```

When I am trying to connect MongoDB server by using Public IP (`132.x.x.x:27017`) it is showing connection timed out.

MongoDB network config, `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

I am starting the MongoDB server by using,

```
sudo mongod
```

inbound rules,

```
27017   tcp 0.0.0.0/0

27017   tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
```

Comment: Have you allowed that port in the security group attached to the instance?

Comment: I have enabled incoming port 27017 from 0.0.0.0 and I think that's why I can connect to the MongoDB server within VPN

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your setup has the following:

- The [elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) is attached to the instance.
- The [security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) allows incoming traffic from the client on the correct port.
- The [network ACL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html) of the subnet that allow for the needed inbound and outbound traffic, or you're using the non-existent/default ACLs, which allow all inbound/outbound traffic.
- An [Internet Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html) is in the same VPC as the instance.
- There is a rule in the subnet's [route table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html) that sends internet-bound traffic to the Internet Gateway.

You may also find [this AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-attach-igw-vpc/) helpful for using the Internet Gateway in your VPC.